# Genetic algorithm for “Hello World”

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

This programme uses a genetic algorithm to get the string `"Hello, World!"`. It can be summarized as follows:

1. Create a random initial population.
2. Let the best reproduce and kill the worst until we get a 'good_enough' result.

I used `doctest` to verify correctness.

```
import doctest
import random

def random_char(start=' ',end='|'):
    """
    Returns a random char from ' ' [SPACE] to '|'.

    >>> random.seed('EXAMPLE')

    >>> random_char()
    'v'
    """
    return chr(random.randint(ord(' '),ord('|')))

def random_string(length):
    """
    Returns a random string os the given length.

    >>> random.seed('EXAMPLE')

    >>> random_string(10)
    "vG5iHyPWG'"
    """
    return ''.join([random_char() for _ in range(length)])

def create_strings_pool(length,number):
    """
    Creates a 'pool' (list) of number strings  of the
    given length.

    >>> random.seed('EXAMPLE')

    >>> create_strings_pool(3,4)
    ['vG5', 'iHy', 'PWG', "'TH"]
    """
    return [random_string(length) for _ in range(number)]

def char_difference(char_1,char_2):
    """
    Return the absolute difference between the ASCII values
    of two chars.

    >>> char_difference('a','b')
    1

    >>> char_difference('a','f')
    5

    >>> char_difference('#','A')
    30
    """
    return abs(ord(char_1) - ord(char_2))

def fitness(candidate,result):
    """
    Detrmines how much similar the candidate string is
    compared to the result. Char distance is counted:
    ex. 'cbr' is more similar to 'car' than 'ccr'
    because 'b' is nearer to 'a' then 'c'.

    >>> fitness('Hfllo','Hello')
    1

    >>> fitness('! QWE','World')
    218

    >>> fitness('ccc','abc')
    3
    """
    fitness = 0
    for index,candidate_char in enumerate(candidate):
        result_char = result[index]
        fitness += char_difference(candidate_char,result_char)
    return fitness

def sort_by_fitness(population,result):
    """
    Returns a list where the most fit elements are at the start.

    >>> sort_by_fitness(['acc','add','asd','acb','aaa','!!!'],'abc')
    ['acc', 'acb', 'add', 'aaa', 'asd', '!!!']
    """
    return list(sorted(population, key = lambda x: fitness(x,result)))

def take_fittest(string_pool,result,elite_number):
    """
    Returns tphe elite_number most fit individuals.

    >>> take_fittest(['acc','add','asd','acb','aaa','!!!'],'abc',3)
    ['acc', 'acb', 'add']
    """
    sorted_string_pool = sort_by_fitness(string_pool,result)
    return sorted_string_pool[:elite_number]

def kill_less_fit(pool,result,must_kill_number):
    """
    Returns all the individual but the kill_number worst ones.

    >>> kill_less_fit(['acc','add','asd','acb','aaa','!!!'],'abc',2)
    ['acc', 'acb', 'add', 'aaa']
    """

    sorted_string_pool = sort_by_fitness(pool,result)
    return sorted_string_pool[:-must_kill_number]

def crossover(father,mother):
    """
    Generates a child by crossover, that is mixing the father and
    the mother.

    >>> random.seed('EXAMPLE')

    >>> crossover('Hello','Noble')
    'Noble'

    # Weird, usually gives a mix.
    """
    son = []
    for index,father_char in enumerate(father):
        mother_char = mother[index]
        if random.random() < 0.50:
            son.append(father_char)
        else:
            son.append(mother_char)
    return ''.join(son)

def mutate(string,mutation_rate):
    """
    Returns a string where each character has (1 - mutation_rate * 0.9) probability
    of being randomly changed.

    >>> random.seed("EXAMPLE")

    >>> mutate("Hello my dear, how are you?",0.7)
    "5HPW' my dDarz h7W =re you?"
    """
    return ''.join([i if random.random() < (mutation_rate*0.9) else random_char() for i in string])

def make_child(father,mother,mutation_rate):
    """
    Generates a child from mother and father using the crossing_over
    and then mutates it accordingly to mutation_rate.

    >>> random.seed("EXAMPLE")

    >>> make_child("Hello","Hulli",0.6)
    'Hulli'
    """
    off_spring = crossover(father,mother)
    if random.random() < mutation_rate:
        return mutate(off_spring,mutation_rate)
    else:
        return off_spring

def genetic_process(result, pool_size, fitness_treshold, mutation_rate,
                    elite_number, max_generations, logging):
    """
    Simulates a gentic evolution.

    1) A random population is created
    2) The most fit individuals get to reproduce and the worst are killed
    until a 'good_enough' individual is born.

    Parametres:
        @ result: The target string you want to obtain.
        @ pool_size: The size of the starting population.
        @ fitness_treshold: How much good you want the solution:
             0 means you want a perfect solution, a high number
             means that even a far solution is ok.
        @ mutation_rate: The probability of random mutations happening:
             0 means no random mutations
             1 means many random mutations
        @ elite_number: The number of best individuals that get to reproduce
             each generation.
        @ max_generations: The maximum number of generations allowed. If a
             solution is not found in that many generations, the best individual
             so far is returned.
        @ logging: True if you want this evolution to print regular output,
             else False.

    Return value:
        @ A string that is inside the fitness_treshold.

    >>> random.seed("Example")

    >>> genetic_process("ABC", 20, 5, 0.8, 6, 4, True)
    Generation number: 0.
    So far the best individual is @E2 with a fitness of 21.
    The top five is ['@E2', 'H3I', '@Ed', '@@ ', 'A1*'].

    Generation number: 1.
    So far the best individual is HEI with a fitness of 16.
    The top five is ['HEI', 'AE2', '@E2', '@E2', 'H3I'].

    Generation number: 2.
    So far the best individual is HE@ with a fitness of 13.
    The top five is ['HE@', 'HEI', 'AES', 'AE2', '@E2'].

    Generation number: 3.
    So far the best individual is AEI with a fitness of 9.
    The top five is ['AEI', 'HE@', 'HEI', 'AES', 'AES'].

    ['AEI', 'HE@', 'HEI', 'AES', 'AES']

    """
    pool = create_strings_pool(len(result),pool_size)
    pool = sort_by_fitness(pool,result)
    for generation_number in range(max_generations):
        best_individuals = take_fittest(pool,result,elite_number)
        # Sometimes I select the second and the third for greater genetic variability
        the_best = random.choice(best_individuals[:3])
        for individual in best_individuals:
            pool.append(make_child(the_best,individual,mutation_rate))
        pool = kill_less_fit(pool,result,elite_number)
        if logging:
            print("""Generation number: {}.
So far the best individual is {} with a fitness of {}.
The top five is {}.\n""".format(
                      generation_number + 1, take_fittest(pool,result,1)[0],
                      fitness(take_fittest(pool,result,1)[0],result),
                      take_fittest(pool,result,5)))
        if fitness(take_fittest(pool,result,1)[0],result) < fitness_treshold:
            break
    return take_fittest(pool,result,5)

def main():
    """ Example of use of the genetic algorithm. """
    TARGET = "Hello, World!"
    POOL_SIZE = 100
    FITNESS_TRESHOLD = 4
    MUTATION_RATE = 1
    ELITE_NUMBER = 20
    NUMBER_OF_GENERATIONS = 10**6
    LOGGING = True

    print((genetic_process(TARGET,POOL_SIZE,FITNESS_TRESHOLD,
                           MUTATION_RATE,ELITE_NUMBER,
                           NUMBER_OF_GENERATIONS, LOGGING)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
    main()
```

Comment: Wow, you really spent some time on this. And your documentation is awesome. Kudos!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- There seems to be some confusion around `mutation_rate`. Firstly, the documentation

  ```
  @ mutation_rate: The probability of random mutations happening:
       0 means no random mutations
       1 means many random mutations
  ```

  conflicts

  ```
  each character has (1 - mutation_rate * 0.9) probability of being randomly changed
  ```
- Secondly, `mutation_rate` is used in two places: in `make_child` to decide whether to call `mutate`, and in `mutate` to decide whether to mutate each character. I'm not familiar with genetic programming practices so I can't say if that is a typical approach, but in any case I would expect to be able to specify the two probabilities separately.
- There are some magic numbers buried in the code, such as the 0.9 above, and the 3 in `genetic_process`. These should be parameters.
- The function `kill_less_fit` seems redundant as one could instead use `take_fittest(pool, result, pool_size)`.
- In `fitness` and `crossover` code like this

  ```
  for index,candidate_char in enumerate(candidate):
      result_char = result[index]
  ```

  could be simplified to this

  ```
  for candidate_char, result_char in zip(candidate, result):
  ```

  which gives me the idea to simplify `fitness` further to

  ```
  return sum(char_difference(candidate_char,result_char)
             for candidate_char, result_char in zip(candidate, result))
  ```
- It is necessary to consult an ASCII table to find out what characters `random_char` can return. It would be clearer and also more flexible to use a string argument that includes all allowed characters.

Answer (score 8):

Python comes with *"batteries included"*, and you can simplify your code by using them. For example:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def fitness(candidate, result):
    """Determine how similar the candidate and result strings are.

    >>> fitness('Hfllo','Hello')
    0.8
    >>> fitness('! QWE','World')
    0.2
    >>> fitness('ccc','abc')
    0.3333333333333333

    """
    return SequenceMatcher(None, candidate, result).ratio()
```

Note that the ratio is always between `0` and `1`, and you would need to invert the ratio or your sorting (`reverse=True`) as low numbers are now worse.

---

Rather than playing with `ord` and `chr`, I would use the constants defined by `string`:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> string.digits
'0123456789'
>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

You could define e.g.

```
CHARACTERS = "".join([" ", string.punctuation, string.digits, 
                      string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_lowercase])
```

then simplify your `random_char` function:

```
def random_char():
    """Provide a randomly-selected character.

    >>> random.seed(0)
    >>> for _ in range(5):
        random_char()


    'l'
    'd'
    '6'
    '\\'
    'F'

    """
    return random.choice(CHARACTERS)
```

---

`crossover` could also be much simpler:

```
def crossover(father, mother, mutation):
    """Return a combination of father and mother with random mutations.

    >>> random.seed(0)
    >>> crossover("hello", "world", 0)
    'welld'
    >>> crossover("hello", "world", 0.5)
    'wclld'
    >>> crossover("hello", "world", 1)
    'aV)Pw'

    """
    return "".join([random.choice(pair) if random.random() > mutation
                    else random_char() for pair in zip(father, mother)])
```

---

I would move the constants from `main` up to the top of the script, so it's easier for someone to open the script and quickly tweak them. Then you can remove `main` entirely, and just call `genetic_process` from the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.